Git Hub - Scheduled reminders: real time alert for failed jobs on CI (for Slack)
I use github integration in slack. I'd like to be notified when a PR has some jobs failing, but I don't care of one in particular, any would work. Do you know what we could put in that part? It's the one of the screenshot:

Could the wildcard work? Did anyone encounter the same problem? Thanks in advance

The best answer I found to this was here. In short, they still didn't put an easy way to get a reminder for any failure on CI (which seems a bit weird but ok), so it's better to specify the specific one you're using. In my case I've set "tests,circleci" as strings.
Not sure if it works yet, but hopefully it does!
